# Why, using Selenium, my program appears in the resource manager network list?

Tags: networking

I use **Selenium** and **VB.Net** to insert some text in a text box of a web page and to press a confirm button on the same page. The program (few lines of code) is called "**chromestarter.exe**".

[image]

As soon as I launch the program, it immediately appears in the list of programs accessing the network, together with "**chromedriver.exe**".

It seems obvious that "**cromediver.exe**" appears, but why does mine appear too? "**chromedriver.exe**" is in the same folder as the program, why does "**chromestarter.exe**" use the network to communicate with it? Wouldn't it be more obvious that would appear "**selenium-manager.exe**", which strangely does not appear?

**EDIT Following the code request of pcalkins:**

```
  Dim driver As ChromeDriver
  Dim Options As New ChromeOptions

  Options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", False)
  Options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", False)
  Options.AddArgument("--window-position=-5000,0")
  Options.AddArgument("start-maximized")
  Options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
  Options.AddExcludedArgument("--enable-automation")
  Options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.images", 2)

  Dim DriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
  DriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True

  driver = New ChromeDriver(DriverService, Options)
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(MyUrl)

  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)

  Dim TextBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("caringEmail"))
  TextBox.SendKeys(UserTxt)

  Dim submitButton = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ta-button"))
  submitButton.Click()
```

**chromestarter.exe** is a very simple program that asks **ONCE** Selenium to insert some text and press a button on the MyUrl Html web page: why appears in the list of network programs? Selenium files are in the program folder and also chromedriver.exe!

NOTE: If I comment all the code after

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(MyUrl)
```

... the program still appears in the network programs list (???) whyle if I write:

```
Process.Start(MyUrl)
```

not... where is the difference that forces chromestarter.exe to send data over the network?

Answer (score 2):

This may be because of Chrome Devtools Protocol (CDP) and/or "BIDI" protocol, which Selenium may use to communicate directly with the browser via socks channel.  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/

Comment: It's entirely this. The chromedriver is a "server" and uses a port to listen for commands, and Selenium can actually reconnect to an existing session if you extract the right keys and localhost URL and port when starting it up. I've done this plenty of times for development work and it helps a lot that you can resume a session instead of starting from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear to me: from what I read it seems to me that it should be "selenium-manager.exe" that has to remain connected and not my application. If to resume a session is not needed, is there any way to communicate it to Selenium in VB.Net?

Comment: the webdriver manager should connect to check if the driver is up to date and download if necessary, but after that there would be no activity.  Still seems like that would be part of your exe...  is it kept separate in VB.NET?  Including some code in your post may help a bit.